# Exporting a database in ddev

Tags: ddev

I'm trying to export a database from my ddev project (on a Mac).

I tried creating a .tarball directory in /var/www/html using the `ddev ssh` command. The docs say, that this directory would show up in my project folder. However, I can't see the directory and thus I'm not sure how I could copy the db-dump from my docker container to my «local» hard-drive.

I also tried using `ddev export-db --file=/tmp/db.sql.gz`

But this throws an error: mysqldump: Got error: 1449: "The user specified as a definer ('redacted'@'%') does not exist" when using LOCK TABLES

I ended up using ddev phpmyadmin for the export, but I'd rather use one of the built in ddev commands, since the database is pretty big and takes quite long to export using phpmyadmin.

Comment: DDEV always uses the user db at hostname db. You may have incorrect settings? Please try a simple project first, from the CMS quickstarts, https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/quickstart/#cms-quickstarts . ddev describe will show proper settings. More details at https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/usage/database-management/#database-management

Comment: I just found out where that other username comes from. The db is an import from a live server. There I created two views with that username as a «definer» (hence the  error message from ddev). Now I just need to find out how to get around this…

Comment: I just created the user in the ddev-db using phpmyadmin and now the export works…

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I had views defined in my database that were imported from a live-db.
The username, that ddev didn't like was set as «definer» in the views (hence the error message when trying to export the db).

I created the user using phpmyadmin and now the export works.